# Counting hits and adding to db but after a while site starts running slow

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, wordpress

I'm faced with this issue only on high volume traffic sites.

Here is the problem and this is wordpress related as well.

I'm counting page hits using an ajax function that gathers a couple details about the page and adds the info to a separate database on the same server.

Everything works fine for a while then the site starts to load slow and at times will say, Can't Connect to Database and the site stops loading for a few seconds or so.

This problem happens mainly I'm guessing because of the massive amount of traffic hitting all the pages on site (over 30-50k a day) and after a while the site is having trouble keeping up with the ajax function requests and or writing to the other database.

Question is, how can I get this to count on large scale traffic sites and not keep getting a slow or crashing database. BTW. Site is on a dedicated server and the wordpress site does have a caching plugin installed.

```
if ($user_role != 'author' && $user_role != 'administrator' &&   $user_role != 'uploader' && $user_role != 'editor' && $user_role != 'contributor') {   
                $insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO " . $pps_new_table_name . "( post_id, post_author, create_date, hit_count, {$browser_column}, {$device_column} ) VALUES (" . $_POST['post_id'] . ",'" . $_POST['post_author'] . "','" . $create_date . "','1','1','1') 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hit_count=hit_count + 1, {$browser_column}= {$browser_column} + 1, {$device_column}= {$device_column} + 1 
                ";
                $results = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($insert));
                $wpdb->show_errors();
            }

        die();
```

Comment: are you sure it's a database problem? Probably you could check the CPU usage per process (`top` on *nix Systems). If it's the Database, check if another Storage Engine (e.G. MySQLs 'Archive') would be suitable. Probably changing 'INSERT'-Statements to 'INSERT DELAYED'-Statements would reduce the load as the insertion would be done after other queries are executed, and the query returns immediately

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It for sure causes a spike in cpu usage. Here is the insert call I'm making.  INSERT IGNORE INTO... how do you suggest that be... I added the full call above.

Comment: Sorry for my comment, I am nearly sure that the Problem is in your Query, Table creation or the server config. 50K Hits are less then 1 per second. Can you please post your OS, MySQL Version - SELECT VERSION(); - your table create and how many rows are in the table

Comment: Hi, i just investigated a little bit. Probably its because the Primary Key (which needs to be looked up in every case) is a _var_char? Even if this is not the reason for the slowdon, I'm sure the [plugin](https://github.com/wp-plugins/post-profit-stats/blob/72d1b056224eb816709178e4bf4ad1b81fc91e04/pps.php) would benefit from modifying it so that it doesn't use a varchar to save dates. So it would be worth trying to modify this.

Comment: Oh, my suggestion of using the 'Archive'-Storage engine is useless, because the counters are updated, but Archive only supports INSERT and SELECT, but nothing else.

Comment: if you have 30 to 50k hits in traffic, you should lookup Load Balancing...